# Yii2, MS-SQL: Not stored value (Cyrillic) in a field of type text

Tags: sql-server, activerecord, encoding, yii2, cp1251

There is a field in MS-SQL, windows-1251, type text. Using activeRecord is added to the value of the field "address" (Cyrillic), formed a query:

```
INSERT INTO [Orders] [Address]) VALUES (0xc8ecff20d4e0ece8ebe8ff20cef2f7e5f1f2e2ee)
```

You receive the error: "type Conflict of operands: varbinary is incompatible with a text type". Varchar - OK. What to do?

Comment: why your query is in this format?

Comment: Yii2 generate the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug PDO in php7, I revert to php5.